# ImageView ArrayList gives NullPointerException

Tags: android, arraylist, imageview, layout-inflater

I'm having some trouble with the logic behind storing an ImageView into an ArrayList.

The application I'm developing keeps track of player statuses in a game. The user first adds Player objects (which keeps track of a status string and a status image to go with it) to an ArrayList (to keep track of them all). Then, after submitting all of the players, a screen pops up inflating a TableRow for each player, containing a button (to view the Player's profile), an ImageView (an icon representing the status), and a TextView (containing the player's status string value).

I don't have a problem with the buttons and loading each player's profile. The problem occurs with loading the "select status" GUI from dialog_select_icon.xml, particularly the ImageView ArrayList. I get a NullPointerException, which doesn't make sense to me because I'm doing it essentially the same way as I did the buttons.

```
//this code runs when user clicks a player's status icon
public void playerStatusIconClicked(View v)
{
    //loop through buttons to determine which player's button was clicked
    for (int i = 0; i < playerList.size(); i++)
    {
        if (v.getId() == playerStatusIVList.get(i).getId())
        {
            calledPlayer = i; //instance variable
            loadStatusIconGUI();
        }//if
    }//for
}//method playerStatusIconClicked


//showStatusIconGUI inflates the "select status icon" GUI
//and handles the user selecting an icon
private void loadStatusIconGUI()
{       
    //inflate the GUI for the showStatusIcon dialog (inflater is an instance variable)
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_select_icon, null);
    //if the list has something in it, start from fresh
    if (!selectStatusIVList.isEmpty())
    {
        selectStatusIVList.clear();        
    }

    //list of icons in the "select status icon" dialog
    selectStatusIVList.add((ImageView) statusIconGUI.findViewById(R.id.statusIV0));
    selectStatusIVList.add((ImageView) statusIconGUI.findViewById(R.id.statusIV1));
    selectStatusIVList.add((ImageView) statusIconGUI.findViewById(R.id.statusIV2));
    selectStatusIVList.add((ImageView) statusIconGUI.findViewById(R.id.statusIV3));
    selectStatusIVList.add((ImageView) statusIconGUI.findViewById(R.id.statusIV4));
    selectStatusIVList.add((ImageView) statusIconGUI.findViewById(R.id.statusIV5));
    selectStatusIVList.add((ImageView) statusIconGUI.findViewById(R.id.statusIV6));

    //create a dialog so user can select an icon
    AlertDialog.Builder selectIconDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    selectIconDialog.setView(view); //set the Dialog's custom view
    selectIconDialog.setTitle(R.string.title_select_icon);

    selectIconDialog.setNegativeButton(R.string.close, null);
    selectIconDialog.show();
}//showStatusIconGUI


//Handle clicks in the "select status icon" dialog
//Assigns a new status to the player
public void statusIconClicked(View v)
{
    Toast message;

    for (int i = 0; i < selectStatusIVList.size(); i++)
    {
        if (v.getId() == selectStatusIVList.get(i).getId())
        {
            message = Toast.makeText(
                MafiaTracker.this, "new status: " statusID[i], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            message.show();
            playerList.get(calledPlayer).setImage(imageID[i]);
            playerList.get(calledPlayer).setStatus(statusID[i]);
        }
    }

    updateViewPlayerGUI(); 
}
```

Note that imageID[i] and statusID[i] are referring to int arrays containing the IDs for each status string and status image.

I can post the xml file but since it's 124 lines long I'd prefer not to. Just know that each ImageView in the xml file DOES have an ID, so I can't figure out why I'm getting these NullPointerExceptions, starting with the "if (!selectStatusIVList.isEmpty())" part, and continuing on with every other call after.

Please help!

Comment: NPE are usually the easiers errors to find, since it simply tells you that you are trying to call something that doesn't exist. In your case, you say that the NPE starts from the call: "if (!selectStatusIVList.isEmpty())", this most likley means that it cannot find selectStatusIVList. Reading your code I can't see where you initiate this list. Post that piece of code so we can have a look. Probably you named it wrong, or the list is out of scope

Comment: Each ImageView in dialog_status_icon.xml has the onClick="statusIconClicked" attribute, so it isn't being called by anything. It's just... there. Haha. I got it from here: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/10/ui-framework-changes-in-android-16.html (see "Easier Click Listeners").

Comment: Thanks Jimmy, you're definitely half-correct. It's an instance variable, but I forgot to initiate it in onCreate(). However, after doing so, I still get the NPE error, except on a different line. Now it occurs when I'm adding the ImageViews to the ArrayList, starting with: selectStatusIVList.add((ImageView) statusIconGUI.findViewById(R.id.statusIV0));.

Comment: Ok, then this tells you that the selectStatusIVList isn't null anymore (since .isEmpty() call works) but it can't find statusIV0 that you are trying to add to the list. Is your ID set correctly in the XML file? e.i android:id="@+id/statusIV0", or the statusIconGUI part might be faulty

Comment: Yep, that was all fine. See the answer below, that was my problem. Oof. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**statusIconGUI** seems to be the main layout xml you used in `setContenView().` 
Consider the line :

```
selectStatusIVList.add((ImageView) statusIconGUI.findViewById(R.id.statusIV0));
```

you are using findViewbyID on statusIconGUI. Do that instead on the view instance of R.layout.dialog_select_icon which you inflated.
so, change the above line to :

```
selectStatusIVList.add((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.statusIV0));
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that was definitely it. I changed it so the LayoutInflater is an instance variable rather than local, and in changing that I must have missed this completely. Awesome!

Comment: I would if I could. (Apparently you need a reputation of 15... I'm still new, eh.)

Answer (score 1):

Initially selectStatusIVList is null. In loadStatusIconGUI check it for null

```
if(selectStatusIVList != null){
    if (!selectStatusIVList.isEmpty())
    {
         selectStatusIVList.clear();        
    }
}else{

     selectStatusIVList = new ArrrayList<Integer>();
}
```